# Set up Vue and @vue/cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I'm trying to create a Vue project. First installed `@vue/cli` with command:

```
PS D:\OpenServer\domains\vue3-example> npm install -g "@vue/cli"
```

Then tried to directly create a Vue project with the command:

```
PS D:\OpenServer\domains\vue3-example> vue create .
```

This resulted in the following result:

[@vue/cli setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxu3e.png)

[vue setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgtQ7.png)

I don't want to reinstall Node because my version of Node is used in other projects. In this case, as I understand it, I need to install the appropriate `@vue/cli` for Node v13.14.0. There were 3 questions:

1. How to remove current `@vue/cli`?
2. Which version of `@vue/cli` is suitable for Node v13.14.0?
3. How to install `@vue/cli` version for Node v13.14.0?

Comment: You can manage multiple versions of Node locally (e.g. using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)).

Comment: Did you see the big notification on every vue-cli page, recommending to use [create-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue) instead?

Comment: You shouldn't ever been using 13 in the first place, it's not a coincidence that it is not supported, odd versions are for experimental purposes. It will likely be safe to upgrade it to 14. There are several concerns regarding node version compatibility, most of them aren't applicable to you as 13 would fail you in those projects that are really sensitive to node version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use command `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli` to revert globally installing `@vue/cli`.
2. According to [Vue documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) versions 4.x are compatible with node v10+ and the support of node 13 [was dropped](https://cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html#for-all-packages) in vue v5.
3. Use command `npm install -g @vue/cli@4` to install vue version 4.x